# How do I control the "long strings" compiler option?

Tags: delphi, string, compiler-construction, delphi-2007, long-integer

How do I control the "long strings" compiler option? I use Delphi 2007

Answer (score 2):

Same as in any earlier version ... [$H](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=$H)

Comment: I prefer `{$LONGSTRINGS ON}`.